# Trying to Test a Controller with a UrlHelper

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

Trying to create a `URLHelper` for testing purposes throws a `NullReferenceException`.

Example:

```
[Fact]
public async void AuthenticateAsyncTest()
{
  // Arrange
  var controller = new Controller(serviceProvider)
  {
    Url = new UrlHelper(new ActionContext()) // Exception thrown
  };

  // Act
  var result = await controller.Authenticate() as ViewResult;

  // Assert
  Assert.NotNull(result);
}
```

Every time I run this Test, the Exception that is thrown in `Url = new UrlHelper(new ActionContext())` is:

Exception.Message:

> Message: System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to
>   an instance of an object.

Exception.StackTrace:

> UrlHelperBase.ctor(ActionContext actionContext)
>   ControllerUnitTest.AuthenticateAsyncTest()

Using:

> xUnit 2.4.1, 
>   Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.2.0,
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Abstractions 2.2.0

To recreate the Exception:

1. Create a empty MVC core 2.2 solution
2. Create a xunit test Project
3. Install the NuGet Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core 2.2.0
4. Write in the test: var Url = new UrlHelper(new ActionContext());
5. Run test

Should look like this:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing;
using Xunit;

namespace XUnitTestProject1
{
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [Fact]
        public void Test1()
        {
            var Url = new UrlHelper(new ActionContext());
        }
    }
}
```

My questions:

1. Is there a bug, or why is this not working?
2. Literature to a workaround or links are appreciated?

Comment: The `ActionContext` is most likely missing some assign dependency

Comment: Url is property of Controller. `new Controller() { Url = something };` AKA Object initializer.

Comment: Do you need an actual helper or can you get away with just mocking it?

Comment: Show what you are actually trying to achieve in a [mcve] the clearly shows the code being tested.

Comment: @SyntaxError Url is the name, since this is an initializing a new class you can just set variables in the Class. That's why you need the {} and use no ; at the end in there. it is a public IUrlHelper Url { get; set; }

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [GitHub source code](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/321327f84b2b22dcff2e9beb06a9a64236c5cced/src/Mvc/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/Routing/UrlHelperBase.cs#L23) referred to by the exception message,

```
protected UrlHelperBase(ActionContext actionContext)
{
    if (actionContext == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(actionContext));
    }

    ActionContext = actionContext;
    AmbientValues = actionContext.RouteData.Values;
    _routeValueDictionary = new RouteValueDictionary();
}
```

The helper is trying to access `actionContext.RouteData.Values` which was not provided in the original example.

Provide the necessary dependencies for the test to flow to completion.

```
[Fact]
public async Task AuthenticateAsyncTest() {
    // Arrange
    var httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext();
    var actionContext = new ActionContext(httpContext, new RouteData(), new ActionDescriptor());
    var controller = new Controller(serviceProvider) {
        Url = new UrlHelper(actionContext)
    };

    // Act
    var result = await controller.Authenticate() as ViewResult;

    // Assert
    Assert.NotNull(result);
}
```

Also avoid using async void for unit tests. Use `Task` instead.

Comment: Thank you very much this seems to do the trick. But I am confused about the fact that for Url = new UrlHelper (new ActionContext ()); doesn't work, since the description of the ActionContext () is:
"Summary: 
Creates an empty Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionContext.
Remarks: 
The default constructor is provided for unit test purposes only."

Comment: according to [source code](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/321327f84b2b22dcff2e9beb06a9a64236c5cced/src/Mvc/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions/ActionContext.cs#L15) default constructor only sets model state. Everythign else would be default.

Comment: I assumed it should work since it worked in MVC core 1.1.
Thank you again for the help.

Answer (score 2):

The second option would be to use the specific constructor. The document states that it should be used for unit testing, more specifically when the ActionContext simply needs to be passed in, but not used by the consuming code.

```
UrlHelper Url = new UrlHelper(new ActionContext { RouteData = new RouteData() });
```

Thank you to navelDirt and pranavkm who replayed on githhub:
https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/6703